# Iteratively INSERTing from a Dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

My question may be out of pure ignorance. Given an arbitrary dataframe of say 5 rows. I want to insert that dataframe into a DB (in my case it's postgresSQL). General code to do that is along the lines of:

```
   postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO table (ID, MODEL, PRICE) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""    record_to_insert = (1, 'A', 100)    cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)
```

Is it a common practice that when inserting more than one row of data, you iterate over your rows and do that? 
It appears that every article or example I see is about inserting a single row to a DB.

Comment: Typically, you just use a for-loop and then update your record_to_insert, then call execute for each iteration

Comment: *dataframe*? Do you mean pandas' DataFrame object which is NOT part of the Python standard library? If so, please tag `pandas` and search for methods to push data frames into DBs.

Comment: Yes, I will adjust that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you could simply loop over your data frame and then do your inserts.

```
for record in dataframe:
    sql = '''INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) 
             VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}')
          '''.format(record[1], record[0], record[2])
    dbo.execute(sql)
```

This is highly simplistic. You may want to use something like sqlalchemy and make surre you use prepared statements. Never overlook security.